# Show colors in gVim embedded terminal

Tags: vim, elementary-os, terminal-emulator, gvim

Does anyone know how to show colors in the gVim embedded terminal?

For instance when you do a `!git diff file.c`.

Answer (score 1):

That built-in terminal is just a very bare one; it doesn't offer capabilities like color highlighting. If you want that, you need to either use terminal Vim, or launch the external command in a separate terminal window:

```
:!gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'git diff file.c'
```